# Primefaces p:log close option

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces log has display but how can it will close option include.

I try below code:

```
<p:log id="log" />
```

In this code log panel is display but close option is never show because i just view log and close it. If there is any way to close log panel

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hide()` method of PrimeFaces logger:

```html
<p:commandButton type="button" value="close" onclick="PrimeFaces.logger.hide()" />
```

Comment: If there is any inbuilt attribute for close in p:log

Comment: Check the docs. If there is nothing mentioned, the chance is 99% it is not there